# Nginx HTML content while redirect

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

When the redirection is configured in nginx, the response contains:

```
<html>[CRLF]
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>[CRLF]
<body bgcolor="white">[CRLF]
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>[CRLF]
<hr><center>nginx</center>[CRLF]
</body>[CRLF]
</html>[CRLF]
```

while debugging:

```
curl -i http://www.domain.com
```

Can I Hide info about nginx from redirect html's?

I have jut managed hide info about nginx by setting `more_set_headers "Server: ";`

Comment: And remember about tokens off;

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at the source, I think you should be able to supply your own `error_page` for 301, 302, 303 and 307.

```
error_page 301 /301.html;

location = /301.html {
    internal;
}
```

(Of course, in this example `/301.html` must exist.)

Answer (score 0):

If your nginx has echo module, you can use error_page redirect to echo

```
error_page  301 /301;

location = /301 {
   internal;
   echo "moved_permanently";
   default_type  "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
}
```